# addEventListener with a form element

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I'm new with Javascript and I'm learning by myself. I have a problem with a form on my page. I just want to test with a simple javascript code that I can manipulate my input "type=submit" by adding a function to it to console.log a string when the form is submitted (I watched it on a video and I wanted to do it by myself).

Here is my code:

```
(function() {
"use strict";

document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('submit', enviar);

    function enviar(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("you submitted the form");
    }

    })();
```

and this is my HTML code:

```
<form id="escribenos" method="post">
                <label for="name">Nombre y Apellido</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+" required value=""/>
                <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
                <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
                  <input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto" />
                <label for="comentario">Mensaje</label>
                <textarea maxlength="250" rows="5" name="comentario" id="comentario" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
                <input id="enviar" value="enviar" type="submit" ></input>
            </form>
```

The problem that I'm having here is that is not working at all.. my ID element is selected properly but I don't know what is wrong with my code. I created a variable and console my ID selected to see if I was getting the right  element from the DOM and I'm getting in the console the right input element. please if someone knows why is not working.

plus: On my text input field I have a regular expression but I'm not getting the output I want.. the goal is that the user has to write at least two names (First and Last), so when they write just one it will be incorrect.. the problem that I'm having with this regular expression if when someone writes more than two names (First, Middle and Last) I DON'T want to make that an incorrect answer because technically is correct. So I need to make a better regular expression to get that result (when the user writes two or more names, not just two) but I don't know too much about Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the element with the `id` `enviar` which is the submit button element. You need to be querying based on the form's element `id` which is `escribenos`. Try running the snippet below and you can see that it has the expected outcome.

```js
(function() {
"use strict";

  document.getElementById('escribenos').addEventListener('submit', enviar);

  function enviar(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("you submitted the form");
  }

})();
```

```html
<form id="escribenos" method="post">
  <label for="name">Nombre y Apellido</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+" required value=""/>
  <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
  <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
  <input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto" />
  <label for="comentario">Mensaje</label>
  <textarea maxlength="250" rows="5" name="comentario" id="comentario" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
  <input id="enviar" value="enviar" type="submit" ></input>
</form>
```